# Windows 7 - Why can I not edit the Start > All Programs Menu if I am an Administrator?

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, start-menu

I want to move around some items in my Windows 7 Start > All Programs Menu, but Windows does not allow me to do so, even though my User Account is an Administrator Account (it is, in fact, the only user Account on the computer).

How can give myself permissions to edit my Windows 7 Start > All Programs Menu?

Comment: You should already have permission.  This a local or domain user?

Comment: Any chance you could add a screenshot showing what you want to move around?

Comment: @Ramhound Local User Account

Comment: When you say "Edit" what action are you trying to perform? Can you list the steps you are doing?

Comment: An unusual situation you're in. I've never encountered it. Perhaps this would help?: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, the start menu looks like this: (Well, I'm using Windows Classic theme.)

[image: Start menu on Windows 7 with "Windows Classic" theme]

The part that you see in this screenshot with "Remote Desktop Connection" all the way to the bottom is the recently-used tools. You can't change those programs. You can change the count of recently-used programs here.

**Changing Recent Programs count on the Start Menu**

1. Right-click "Start" and select **Properties**.
2. On "Start Menu" tab, select **Customize...*.
3. At the bottom of this screen, you see two boxes with numbers. The first one is number of recent programs to display.

Now, if you want to change the programs above the separator (in my screenshot it's Internet Explorer down to Windows Powershell), you can adjust those easily. Those are the items **Pinned to the Start Menu**. You should be able to rearrange them by click-and-dragging. If you want to remove them, right-click the item and select "unpin from Start Menu."

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm referring to items in the "All Programs" menu.